# How to create a temporary table and then join it to another table twice

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have a table called pairs_of_products that has the following two columns:

```
product_id_1, product_id_2
```

I would like to create a temporary table called monthly_orders that will have the following columns:

```
product_id, monthly_orders
```

and then join it to pairs_of_products so that I can end up with a new table with the following columns

```
product_id_1, product_id_2, monthly_orders_1, monthly_orders_2
```

I am not sure how to go about this in an efficient way - though I am sure that I would like to only create `monthly_orders` once.

Comment: What database system are you using? It matters quite a bit as far as what the "right" answer is.

Comment: It should be Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: create `monthly_orders`.

Step 2: query it:

```
SELECT pp.product_id_1,
       pp.product_id_2,
       mo1.monthly_orders AS monthly_orders_1,
       mo2.monthly_orders AS monthly_orders_2
  FROM pairs_of_products pp
  JOIN monthly_orders mo1
    ON pp.product_id_1 = mo1.product_id
  JOIN monthly_orders mo2
    ON pp.product_id_2 = mo2.product_id
;
```

---

**Edited to add:** Or, in one step:

```
  WITH monthly_orders AS
       ( SELECT ... AS product_id,
                ... AS monthly_orders
           FROM ...
       )
SELECT pp.product_id_1,
       pp.product_id_2,
       mo1.monthly_orders AS monthly_orders_1,
       mo2.monthly_orders AS monthly_orders_2
  FROM pairs_of_products pp
  JOIN monthly_orders mo1
    ON pp.product_id_1 = mo1.product_id
  JOIN monthly_orders mo2
    ON pp.product_id_2 = mo2.product_id
;
```

(using *[subquery factoring](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+subquery+factoring)*).

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there some special syntax that I can use to create monthly orders within the same query? My issue is that I'm pulling everything from a data warehouse and I can't store it anywhere...

Comment: @BerkU.: That will depend on your DBMS (PostgreSQL or MySQL or Oracle or SQL Server or whatnot).

Comment: Within the same statement? Not so easily, but within the same transaction, you can use CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm

Comment: @NathanHenkel: Sorry, you probably missed this, but I had actually already updated my answer to explain how to do it. (`WITH` for the win!)